# CGPointMake Issue for iPhone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cgpoint

I have 2 buttons, and I want them to fall down the screen, and when they hit the specified Y axis (411), they become hidden and are set to NULL, and then the HP label is deducted -1 point. But when I use my if statement, it jumps the other button up the screen. Here's the code:

```
- (void)fall {
i += 1;
btn.center = (CGPointMake(btn.center.x, btn.center.y +5));

if (btn.center.y >= 411) {
    btn.hidden = TRUE;
    btn = NULL;
    startBtn.enabled = TRUE;
    hpLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [hpLbl.text intValue]-1];
}
```

}

```
- (void)fall2 {
i += 1;
btn2.center = (CGPointMake(btn2.center.x, btn2.center.y +5));

if (btn2.center.y >= 411) {
    btn2.hidden = TRUE;
    btn2 = NULL;
    startBtn.enabled = TRUE;
    hpLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [hpLbl.text intValue]-1];
}
```

}

Like I said,  fall = a button, and fall2 = another button. The error is happening on:

```
hpLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [hpLbl.text intValue]-1];
```

Comment: "But when I use my if statement, it jumps the other button up the screen" - What do you mean? When are you calling fall / fall2 methods?  "The error is happening on:" - which error?

Comment: @Piotr when I click start, they both fall. Then, once one of them crosses the Y axis on 411, it deducts -1 point from the hpLbl. Then, the other button quickly changes it's position to y:347. It was hard to word this, but it basically just jumps upwards then falls down again.

Comment: @Piotr and the error is when I deducted the point from the hpLbl. When I deleted it, it fell and worked fine, but when I re-added it, it has the issue I explained above.

Comment: Maybe providing more code might help. Hard to tell what's wrong in current solution.

Comment: How is button jumping related to setting a text on a UILabel? You might have to post the animation code as well and the method which calls fall and fall2.